# Apache Proxy requested based on URL parameter

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, proxypass

Remapping Apache to a TC backend, but I would like to filter out unless a certain parameter is set.

ie. `http://server/myapp?project=mine` maps to `http:server:8080/myapp?project=mine`

There will be more parameters (though I will enforce `project=mine` as the last).

`ProxyPassMatch` works but not for parameters.

I tried

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} project=mine
RewriteRule (.*) localhost:8080
```

Seems to be close, but testing in CURL I get: This document moved...

Which I do not get with `ProxyPass` or `ProxyPassMatch`

What am I missing ?

Tips/pointers/RTFMs appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `P` flag on the `RewriteRule` to pass the request through mod_proxy, as opposed to being treated as an external 3xx redirect (ie. "this document has moved" msg).

For example, if used directly in the `<VirtualHost>` container:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)project=mine$
RewriteRule ^/myapp$ http://server:8080$0 [P]
```

The *condition* checks for the URL parameter `project=mine` at the end of the query string. Only the URL-path `/myapp` is matched (as in your example).

The `$0` backreference contains the entire URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. This simply saves repeating `/myapp` in the *substitution* string.

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} project=mine
> RewriteRule (.*) localhost:8080
> ```

There are a few issues with your initial attempt (apart from the missing `P` flag):

- You are matching any URL-path, eg. `/anotherapp` would also be caught. But this is also discarded.
- The regex `project=mine` matches that string anywhere in the query string, even as part of other URL params. eg. `fooproject=miner` would also match.
- `localhost:8080` is not a valid substitution string.

Comment: Thank you.  I did realize I was dropping my app and definitely do not want that.  I think this has shown me enough to finish my task.